# How can I fix an invalid argument error when setting up an API trigger?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

When attempting to create a trigger to pull fresh API data in google sheets, I get this error: [Invalid Argument]

[image: error message]

I used free open source code for importJSON found [here](https://gist.github.com/paulgambill/cacd19da95a1421d3164)

It works when I type in a cell "importJSON("URL") so it seems to be an error specifically related to setting up a trigger to refresh the data upon-open, or at timed intervals.

I am a novice, and i am surprised i got this far trying to set this sheet up. So I do not understand the problem, and I do not understand other solutions people have gotten when I research this invalid argument.

I am hoping someone here will be able to look at my specific situation and find out where this problem is, and be able to explain the solution in a way that I can understand it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: From your error message of `Exception: Invalid argument: http://[object%20Object]`, I'm worried that you might have used an object instead of a string value. For example, when `UrlFetchApp.fetch({})` is run, an error of `Exception: Invalid argument: http://[object%20Object]` occurs. In order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide your current script and provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue?